# Symfony 2 redirect instead undefined offset exception

Tags: php, symfony, exception, doctrine

My question for today is how to do in Symofny2 to redirect me to route instead show exception. For example i execute select in database and in return i get

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

So how can i redirect this exception to some route ? i use:

```
try{ 
   myMetdod()
}catch(ContextErrorException $e){
   $this->redirectToRoute('myRoute');
}
```

But it wont take any effect. Please help

Comment: Your need the return the `$this->redirectToRoute()` otherwise it's just calling it and moving on. Although you should probably look at your sorting the error in your database query. Could you post that as well?

Comment: The redirectToRoute() method is simply a shortcut that creates a Response object that specializes in redirecting the user.
It depends on context and error - you should not ignore errors and redirect to other route...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return and call the method generateUrl()

```
try{ 
   myMetdod()
}catch(ContextErrorException $e){
   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('redirect-path'));
}
```